# Get all key, values from nested json

Tags: javascript, json

I' trying to fetch some `json` data, structured like so:

```
{"Points": 
       {"90": 
             {"0": {"name": "John Phillip", "slug": "john"},
             {"1": {"name": "Mark Anthony", "slug": "mark"},
             ...
       },
       ...
 }
```

With:

```
 async getData(93) {
      const res = await fetch("/json/sample.json");
      const data = await res.json();

      // round to the lowest multiple of five 5: 92->90, 93->90
      const roundToLowest5 = x => Math.floor(x/5)*5

      // Here a I access the key of '90', from outer key 'Points'
      console.log(data.Points[roundToLowest5(value).toString()])

      return this.setState({ data });
    }
```

So far, console shows me all data for my outer key 'Points':

```
{0: {…}, 1: {…}, 2: {…}, 3: {…}, 4: {…}, 5: {…}, 6: {…}, 7: {…}, 8: {…}, 9: {…}, 10: {…}, 11: {…}}
```

---

Considering that all index keys here ("0", "1", "2"...) are strings, how do I get all key, values for each index key?

Expected output:

```
{"name":"John Phillip", "slug": "john"}, {"name":"Mark Anthony", "slug":"mark"}...
```

Comment: please share the expected result

Comment: please refer to edit

Comment: You cannot get `{"name":"John Phillip", "slug": "john", "name":"Mark Anthony", "slug":"mark"}` in single object. Since `name` and `slug` keys are duplicte so their values will be overridden

Comment: I have separated the objects, please refer to edit

Comment: The `.toString()` part is not required

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Object.values to return an array of values of all keys

```
  console.log(Object.values(data.Points[roundToLowest5(value).toString()]))
  //this will return [{"name":"John Phillip", "slug": "john"}, {"name":"Mark Anthony", "slug":"mark"}...]
```